# how to map movement keys to utf-8 non latin character in non-us-latin1 keyboard

Tags: vim

I am using Turkish F keyboard layout and using vim default key movements in default settings is painfull for me since the keys are different places than latin1 keyboard. I would like to map for example j to ü character which basically `u00FC` `ü` character in my keyboard which is in a convenient place.

I have tried following but did not work in my .vimrc file.

`norepmap j <C-v>u00FC`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it both backwards and wrong.

First, Vim understands `ü` perfectly, without the need for any `<C-v>` trick or Unicode translation.

Second, in a mapping, the left-hand side is the key combination you want to press and the right-hand side is what you want to happen. In your case, you want `j` to happen when you press `ü` so your mapping should look like this:

```
noremap ü j
```

Third, the `:help 'langmap'` option seems better suited to your needs than a potentially large collection of mappings:

```
set langmap=üj
```

Fourth, `hjkl` are not that useful to begin with, especially if you don't touch-type. If I were you I would focus my attention on more useful topics.

Comment: Hello, I am really grateful. I just blindly applied without reading much documentation by looking at blogs, forums. I have never heard langmap which seems really the solution of my problem. Thank you really for pointing it out.

Comment: Forget blogs and forums, `:help user-manual` is the real deal.

Comment: vim-plug creates a problem with langmap.  I returned using mapping. However following mapping does not work  ````noremap t h
noremap m k 
noremap ç m 
noremap k j 
noremap ü t
noremap ğ ;
````